# Automatically download all attachments from Gmail with a specific label

Tags: gmail, google-drive, gmail-labels

Is there a way do download every attachment within a label? I want every PDF invoice I get to be put in my file system. So I figured I'd need Google Drive. But I only did find some Chrome extensions that make it easier to save them manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll not be able to do that with the Gmail web client. Filters there can only act on messages by responding to them, applying labels, etc. You'll need a third-party tool like a desktop e-mail client, but even then you'll probably need _another_ tool added to that.

Answer (score 7):

Try Zapier. Looks like [this Zap](https://zapier.com/z/vv/zapbook/gmail/google-drive/5984/save-gmail-attachments-to-drive/) will let you save attachments to Google Drive based on a specific label you label your emails with.

[image]

Comment: I think this applies to only new incoming mail with that label?

Answer (score 5):

You can install the [Send to Google Drive](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/) script and it will automatically download all Gmail attachments that have the label *GoogleDrive* to your Drive folder.

> Assuming that you are logged in to your Google account, create a copy
>   of [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aofk8L6brI_edGRCUGt3aDZya0Z5LXRNRllYS3lIUWc&newcopy=true) in your Google Drive. Open the sheet
>   and you should see a new Gmail menu – click Initialize and grant the
>   necessary permissions. Next go the Gmail menu again and select Run.

The script runs in the background and will watch your "GoogleDrive" label for any new messages to process.

Comment: FYI the google sheet now [points to a freemium chrome extension](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/). That blog post links to the relevant google apps script [here](http://ctrlq.org/code/19053-send-to-google-drive). As a side note, labnol.org has been a great resource. Thanks Amit!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the other answers describe how to do this to Google Drive, but you said you wanted them downloaded to your (I presume local) file system.

Check the description [here](http://lifehacker.com/5156067/how-can-i-download-every-attachment-from-gmail) for a detailed guide to using Thunderbird for this purpose.

With a simple modification, you can download only the attachments you want (in Step 3, just choose the appropriate folder/label or other subset).

EDIT:

Since writing the above, I have discovered a much simpler & easier to use solution. The tool [Mail Attachment Downloader from GearMage](http://gearmage.com/maildownloader.html) does exactly what you requested and also provides a great deal of flexibility. I've started using it myself and I am very pleased with the results. It also works with Yahoo, Hotmail and almost any other mail server that supports POP3 or IMAP.

I am adding the following in case you decide to go with my pre-edit answer, so that all parts of this answer can "stand on their own":

1. Download and install Thunderbird
2. To Thunderbird add the AttachmentExtractor extension from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/556)
3. Once it's been added you can right-click and choose "Extract Selected Attachments to..." from the menu

Want more detailed instructions? You can try that link above.

Personally, I now recommend using the standalone, dedicated tool by GearMage.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't offer a built-in feature to download the attachment of several emails "at the same", but there are several ways to achieve the desaired result.

1. Use a third-party service. You could ask about recomendations on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
2. Use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) to send the attachments to Google Drive, then use the Google Drive desktop client to automatically download the attachments to your computer's desktop.

   - There are at least one answer about this on this question.
3. Use a POP / IMAP desktop email client that includes a feature that automatically add the attachments to local folder

   - An old version of [Eudora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudora_(email_client)) put all the email messages attachments in a local folder. I don't know if there are a version that works with modern operative system versions, but this reference could help you to further research and find what you are looking for.
   - Some email desktop clients could be extendend by using add-ons or even by using a programming language like Microsoft Outlook